# What environment do I need for gluonium entities to thrive in?

Tags: aliens, stars, materials, dyson-spheres

[Gluons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) are the particles that hold quarks together. The way they do this allows them to hold each other together in the form of [gluonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball).

Gluonium only appears at high temperatures such as those reached in collider experiments. It also quickly decays in isolation, but I want aliens who are made of gluonium, so I need an environment that they can form in, without decaying. I'm willing to handwave the decay problem by positing that when not isolated, gluonium structures can endure. But I don't want to handwave the temperature problem. I haven't been able to find an exact range for the temperature needed for IRL gluonium, with which to compare stellar temperatures (my assumption so far has been that gluonium structures might emerge in extremely hot stellar environments, but I don't know if there are stars that get hot enough?).

An alternative idea: gluonium entities are artificially produced by vast collider arrays (powered by Dyson machinery, say). Then maybe humans author them, or some other "normal" aliens did. But if I could come up with "natural" glueball life forms, I might prefer that.

**What temperature am I looking for?**

Comment: We usually ask questioners to wait at least 48 hours before awarding accepted answer status. That being said, you might just end-up awarding it to the answer already given anyhow, but we ask you to be aware that the membership is present in all time zones nonetheless.

Comment: Got it. I kinda wondered if I should wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1.7 to 3.5 trillion degrees kelvin (perhaps less)

[This preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.07730.pdf) does a wide range of calculations.  Someone here may understand them, but the table on Page 15 ranges from around 150 to 300 MeV.  The Boltzmann constant (average energy per particle per degree kelvin) is 86.17 mceV/K, so we are talking about 1.7 to 3.5 TK (trillions of degrees Kelvin or Celsius)  That appears to be the upper limit for glueball stability (deconfinement).

[Another preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0504390) describes gluon formation in cooling [quark star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star)s in the 2-flavor color phase.  This is the only paper I found that specifically talks about glueballs in neutrons stars.  (see [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04257) for description of a quark-gluon superfluid at the core of a star produced by a neutron star merger)  These glueballs seem to be too *cold* to be stable, as best as I can gather, and "immediately" decay, and have energy modelled at 0.8 to 10 MeV = 10-100 GK (10 to 100 billion degrees Kelvin).  But how quickly is "immediately" for something made out of such hot, exotic matter, which undergoes many more interactions in a given period of time?

Comment: Darn, it doesn't seem like stars get THAT hot even at their cores (which could be inhospitable for these beings, for general reasons, anyway...).

Comment: @Kristian:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16633 talks about the possibility of quark matter in very heavy neutron stars, based on a combination of temperature and pressure.

Comment: @HDE226868 I agree it seemed to be talking about the upper bound of temperature; but if they can be deconfined at that temperature, they can exist at about that temperature.  More importantly, if the aliens are made of gluonium, we want to do some sort of "biochemistry", which intuition suggests should be fairly near the point where glueballs break down entirely.

Comment: @HDE226868  I added above *one* paper about glueballs in neutron stars, and that says they can exist at the temperature you say, but "immediately" decay...

Comment: @MikeSerfas That's really interesting - I'll take a look. That definitely addresses my concern, +1.

Comment: The [cheela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg) might be a good example of how to solve the "but how quickly is 'immediately'" question?

Comment: The general question of "how fast time flows" is interesting.  I'm suspicious that it is simply proportional to the temperature, and that for this reason, to some quite poor approximation, every doubling of the age of the universe takes up the same amount of subjective time for the organisms coded by that physics.  But is it so?